# Getting Date object in Swift using full name timezone?

Tags: swift, date, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nstimezone

I want to get Date object using parameters. With time zone abbreviation and with identifier it is possible. But can we get with full name timezone string.

```
"dateTime": "2017-04-15T12:00:00",
"timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is certainly possible but not very simple. Let's just take all possible time zones and compare their localized description with the one you have:

```
let dateString = "2017-04-15T12:00:00"
let timeZoneName = "Pacific Standard Time"
let locale = Locale(identifier: "en-US")

let knownTimeZones = TimeZone.knownTimeZoneIdentifiers.flatMap { TimeZone(identifier: $0) }
let timeZone = knownTimeZones.first {
     // I don't know what type of name you have, `.standard` does not have to be correct
     $0.localizedName(for: .standard, locale: locale) == timeZoneName
}

print(timeZone)

if let timeZone = timeZone {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.locale = locale
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
    dateFormatter.timeZone = timeZone

    print(dateFormatter.date(from: dateString))
}
```

Comment: I wish to understand how this works. To my understanding, dateString & time zone implies that when this info is saved It was 12 AM PST April 15, 2017. Output from the lines above is 2017-04-15 19:00:00 +0000. Now this output shows which time zone? Device time zone? If not, how can i convert any time in such format to device time zone at once. I am sorry for asking for explanation but It is very confusing for me to cross check whether I am getting correct time.

Comment: When you print `Date` in Xcode console, it is printed in UTC (GMT-0) time zone. The date itself is a moment in time, it does not have a time zone. If you want to display it in a specified time zone, you need to create a formatter with that time zone and use it to create string representation of that date.

Comment: However, note that time zone name is often misleading because the actual offset changes due to daylight saving during the year.